# How to increase the maximum file size to load via File upload" page in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I am using the **Strapi v3.0.0-beta.18.7**. 
I have the problem with loading files into strapi via ***"File upload"*** page.

> I tried to load 9 MB .mp4 video. The video started to load and then the process just stopped and I can not see the video in the file list.

What is the maximum file size to load in strapi and how to increase it?

Comment: Solved the problem by setting the max size of the file into /config/request.json

 `"formidable": {
  "maxFileSize": SIZE IN KB
}`

Comment: But if the file needs to load for a few minutes it is hard to monitor whether file uploading or not and what percentage is already uploaded.